# Which design pattern is suitable

Tags: design-patterns

I'm new to design patterns.

I have a singleton class named A, which has a state class named B inside it. There are also several specific management classes C,D,E,F inside this class A, which are independent of each other, but they all use the state class B and update the state of B when performing specific operations. B itself can also update the state by itself, and B needs to call a method in the CDEF class based on the update.

Which design pattern should be chosen to reduce the coupling degree between modules?

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for [the software engineering stack exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This seems like something a weird teacher would ask, anyway, take a look at [the mediator pattern](https://springframework.guru/gang-of-four-design-patterns/mediator-pattern/)

Comment: Definitely mediator pattern